# How to create object based on an interface where each value is set to 'true'?

Tags: typescript

Given an interface

```
interface Foo {
  value1: boolean;
  value2: boolean;
}
```

how may I create an object based on this interface that has all its value set to `true` (or false)?

Something that might illustrate what I mean:

```
const object: Foo = { [keyof Foo]: true }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you'll have to create the object as you would do in normal js. TS types don't exist at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

We should create a class that `implements` the interface and use it to construct new objects:

```
class FooImpl implements Foo {
  
  constructor(value1: boolean, value2: boolean) {
       this.value1 = value1;
       this.value2 = value2;
  }
}
```

and later use it:

```
const F = new FooImpl(true, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the opposite and derive `Foo` from your variable:

```
const object = {
  value1: true,
  value2: true,
};

type Foo = typeof object;
```

If you *need* an interface (for its marginal differences in behavior vs `type`) you could do something like this:

```
type _Foo = typeof object;

interface Foo extends _Foo {}
```